# Add space between two lines

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I need to add space between two lines by using OpenCV or PIL.

[image: example image]

Comment: Do you know the height(in pixels) at which you want to add the space?

Answer (score 1):

If the lines vary "sufficiently" in their length, then the following approach might be useful:

- Inverse binarize the image using [`cv2.threshold`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57).
- Dilate the image with a horizontal line kernel using [`cv2.dilate`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga4ff0f3318642c4f469d0e11f242f3b6c) to emphasize the lines.
- Sum all pixels row-wise using [`np.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), and calculate the absolute differences between the rows using [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html).
- There will be "steps" in the differences between the rows, which resemble the step between the lines. Set up a threshold and find the proper indices using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).
- Insert white lines in the original image before the found indices using [`np.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html). In the below example, the index was chosen manually. Work has to be done to properly automatize this: Exclude "steps" to "background", find "steps" between multiple lines.

Here comes a code snippet:

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import io              # Only needed for web grabbing images, use cv2.imread for local images

# Read and binarize image
image = cv2.cvtColor(io.imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/56g7s.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
_, image_bin = cv2.threshold(image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Dilate rows by using horizontal line as kernel
kernel = np.ones((1, 51), np.uint8)
image_dil = cv2.dilate(image_bin, kernel)

# Sum pixels row-wise, and calculate absolute differences between the rows
row_sum = np.sum(image_dil / 255, 1, dtype=np.int32)
row_sum_diff = np.abs(np.diff(row_sum))

# Just for visualization: Summed row-wise pixels
plt.plot(row_sum)
plt.show()

# Find "steps" in the differences between the rows
step_thr = 100
step_idx = np.where(row_sum_diff > step_thr)[0]

# Insert n lines before desired index; simple hard-coding here, more work needs to be done for multiple lines
n_lines = 5
image_mod = np.insert(image, step_idx[1] + 1, 255 * np.ones((n_lines, image.shape[1]), np.uint8), axis=0)

# Result visualization
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.imshow('image_dil', image_dil)
cv2.imshow('image_mod', image_mod)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The dilated, inverse binarized image:

[image: dilated, inverse binarized]

The visualization of the "steps":

[image: steps]

The final output with `n = 5` inserted white lines:

[image: Output]

As you can see, the result isn't perfect, but that's due to the original image. In the corresponding row, you have parts of the first and second line. So, a proper distinction between these two isn't possible. One might add a very small morphological closing to the output to get rid of these artifacts.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast response as well as awesome answer.